# xsl code formatting on attribute break reading into it

Tags: xml, xslt, visual-studio-2012

Question: When looking at a single node of a xsl file to pic up a object, should it matter how the xsl code file is formatted?

Example code:
getting the object in js:

```
origObject = document.getElementById("objImg" + objImageNodes(iCount).selectSingleNode(strIDNodeName).text);
```

the node format xsl:

```
<xsl:attribute name="id">objImg<xsl:value-of select="ID_PIC"/>`</xsl:attribute>
```

Which works fine, BUT if that xsl shows as this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="id">
    objImg<xsl:value-of select="ID_PERS_PIC"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

the origObject is null.

Why does it matter how the xsl file is formatted, isn't it pretty much like a flat file....

VS2012, FrameWork 4.5, XSL:stylesheet version 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the white space before the text the `id` of the element is not a string starting with `objImg` but a string starting with a line break followed by some blanks (or a tab, not sure what you have in there) followed by `objImg`.

Comment: I did a auto format command key (mine is Crtl+K+D) to show it that way.
So there should be nothing in that section in terms of spaces tabs etc because I didn't put it there, but is it being read that way....

Comment: You do have a line break after the `xsl:attribute` start tag and then further white space before the `objImg` and that will be all part of the attribute value unless you use the first format you have shown or use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="concat('objImg', ID_PERS_PIC)"/>` to avoid any such problems.

Comment: interesting, and annoying.

Comment: You haven't said what text editor you did this auto-format command in. It would be nice to know so we can avoid that editor!

Comment: @MichaelKay - Sorry I did have the VS2012 tag (but that was confusing), but this is in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5. (I would use VS 2017 but not my choice....)